# fscanf file - stop reading current line?

Tags: c

i'm writing a program, reading a text file. The text file will have a structure like this:

```
Apple 0.19 

Juice 0.89

Bread 1.19
```

Now the program should read (using fscanf and strings with a known buffer) the first line until it reaches a blank shape (between the name and the number) and go into the next line without reading the number, so it can give me a list without the numbers. 
Means it's like "if fscanf reads a blank, go into next line". How can i do that?

Comment: Why don't you just read the number and ignore it? For example, using `fscanf("%s %f\n",charArr,&floatNum)`, with a space between the `%s` and the `%f`.

Comment: You just answered your own question.Don't expect for us to write code for you.

Comment: `fscanf()` is not really a good option. Because with a fixed format that fscanf expects, it can't handle blanks *and* a certain format you describe. Use `fgets()` instead and parse it with `sscanf()`.

Comment: it would be easier if there would be something like a command for it. I dont ask for a full code, just for a fitting command. I am too stupid to find the right thing in the internet :/

Comment: @Tecknator It's all speculation and guess-work until you show the real code to find exactly what/where your problem is.

Comment: General advice: Don't use the words "too stupid" to describe yourself, there are plenty of other users here that will most likely do it for you anyway.

Comment: E.g [sample](http://ideone.com/aHPgee)

Comment: @barak manos Note: The advise to use "a space between the `%s` and the `%f`" does not change `scanf()` operation.  The same results occur with or without a leading space before `"%f"`.

Comment: @chux: Thanks (again) for your educative notes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// this will work for a line such as "Pumpkin pie 1.50"
char *sptr = strrchr (linestring, ' ');   // find last space
if (sptr)                                // if one was found
    *sptr = 0;                            // truncate string
```